# Monkey on a Flagpole

Tags: calculation-puzzle

A 3 feet tall, hungry monkey is trying a reach a magical banana placed on top of a flagpole.

The flagpole is 25 feet in height and is slippery to grasp.

Every Odd numbered Jump, the monkey climbs 3 feet and slides down 2 feet, while for every Even jump the monkey climbs 4 feet and slides down 3 feet.

Question : How much length in Odd jumps does the monkey take to reach the top of the flagpole? and Why?

Comment: @mmking thanks for bringing it to my attention. Should I delete the question or simply wait for it to generate enough votes to close ?

Comment: I'm voting to re-open because this brainteaser - often in the form of a snail or frog trying to get out of a hole - is a popular [job interview question](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/A-frog-is-at-the-bottom-of-a-30-meter-well-Each-day-he-summons-enough-energy-for-one-3-meter-leap-up-the-well-Exhausted-QTN_70534.htm) (although it's my opinion that anyone who thinks this kind of question has any predictive value at all for job performance is deeply deluded - it's very bad interviewing practice). http://www.newyorker.com/tech/elements/why-brainteasers-dont-belong-in-job-interviews

Comment: I'm calling it a brainteaser rather than just a maths problem because the focus is usually on avoiding the [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) when the animal gets to the top but before they (in the same cycle) slip back down again. Sometimes it's expressed in terms of "goes up *n* feet during the day and slips back *m* feet at night", and the answerer is expected to distinguish between 'days' (as versus nights) and '24-hour-periods'. So there's often a 'trick question' element to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 10 odd jumps are required

The monkey climbs, in essence, one foot per jump. Assume it can reach to the top of its 3-foot height, in which case it only needs to attain a maximum height of 22 feet to reach the banana.

The important jump is the final one:

> If the last jump would be an even jump, we find that the monkey can reach the banana from 18 feet before sliding back down. If it would be odd, the monkey would previously have to be at a height of at least 19 feet.

To reach these heights at one net foot per jump:

> the monkey would need to jump 18 times (9 odd, 9 even) to reach an 18 foot height. This would make their next jump an 'odd' one (10 odd), meaning they wouldn't reach the banana. One more 'even' jump (10 even)would be required after that to grab the fruity prize.

I apologise if I've said metres instead of feet at any point. Still having to resist the urge to go through and convert from Imperial to Metric

Answer (score 1):

There will be

> 22 jumps, 11 odd, 11 even
>
>  Every jump until the end nets you 1 foot. After the 21st jump (odd), the monkey will be at 21 feet. Then the monkey jumps 4 feet (even) and gets the banana.

Comment: You're correct to discard the sliding mechanic for the last jump, but you've forgotten about the height of the monkey!

Answer (score 1):

> 22, because we can guarantee that after 25 - $(3,4)max$ = 21 jumps, it climbs 21 meters. Since 22 is even, the last day will see it climb to the top without sliding back.